# Read output from exec kotlin

Tags: java, io, kotlin, output

I need to exec a jar file and redirect the output from my executed process to the output of my main process.

I using the following code :

```
val command = "java.exe -version"
val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
val buf = p.getInputStream()
val inputAsString = buf.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
println(inputAsString)
```

I have no output...

I have tested this code :

```
val command = "cmd /c chcp"
val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
val sc = Scanner(p.inputStream)
println(sc.nextLine())
sc.close()
```

I have an output but when I replace "cmd /c chcp" I have an error...

How can I read the output of "test.jar" which write "ok" for example ?

Comment: Most programs are sending their diagnostics output to STDERR instead of STDOUT (like `java -version`). Have you tried reading from there: `val buf = p.errorStream`?

Comment: For java -version reading the errorStream work. But when I use "java -jar myfile.jar someargs" It didn't work...

Comment: Do you know if `myfile.jar` prints to stderr or stdout? You should consider using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec`, because then you can choose to redirect stderr to stdout so you only have to read from the 1 stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
    val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
    p.waitFor()
    val stdOut = IOUtils.toString(p.inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8)
    val stdErr = IOUtils.toString(p.errorStream, Charsets.UTF_8)
```

using `org.apache.commons.io` for `IOUtils`